# A question about a line from Hook

Tags: dialogue, hook

When Peter (Robin Williams) is being driven home in a cab, he makes fun of the driver's name 'Neville', asking:

> Is that English?

What does it mean?

Comment: I'm assuming it's because he forgot his name (calling him Nigel/Norman beforehand) and it's his way of breaking the ice. By asking if it's English, it suggests the reason he is confused is because he doesn't know if the name is foreign or not. It's *obviously* English, hence the joke and the laugh. That's just a guess though!

Answer (score 2):

The joke is that most taxi drivers are foreign, with names that are difficult for Americans to pronounce.  Sometimes cabbies give themselves English sounding names to make it easier for their passengers.  Think about that scene from Horrible Bosses when the OnStar employee directs the guys to the bar where they met Jamie Foxx.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is downvoted.